# accessing special character array within awk

Tags: arrays, awk

I want to print the contents of an array that contains special characters using `awk`. Below is the `awk` code in which I am trying to print array `ARRAY` where `xx` is the index of the array.

But the code below prints `ARRAY1`, `ARRAY2`.... instead of printing the contents of array.

```
awk 'BEGIN { xx=0; }
{
    if (index($0, "ns:translate") > 0) {
        print $0;
        print "<Name xml:lang=\"sp\"> ARRAY" xx "</Name>";
        xx++;
    } else {
        print $0;
    }
}' $1
```

The contents of the array are:

```
[\u8815S - Perce ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u573  
\u8915S - add ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u583  
\u8615S - sub ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u573  
\u8835S - mult ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u593  
\u8865S - div ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u993
    .....]
```

The array has close to 100 elements.  Can anyone please help me access the special character array within `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
print "<Name xml:lang=\"sp\">" ARRAY[xx] "</Name>";
```

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements

Comment: with that also I dont get the array contents. I get a blank instead

Comment: Can you include the rest of the awk script that populates ARRAY?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a good guess that "ARRAY" is not actually an awk array but instead exists in the OS you're calling awk from? Well, in case it helps here's how you'd write your awk script above IF "ARRAY" actually were an awk array:

```
awk '1
index($0, "ns:translate") {
   printf "<Name xml:lang=\"sp\">%s</Name>\n", ARRAY[xx++]
}' $1
```